# page flashes when scroll to top using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use the following code to scroll to the top of the page:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".example").offset().top
}, 750);
```

unfortunately, when I click on the button that triggers the animation, the page flashes. How can I stop the page from flashes as it scrolls to the top?

Comment: chances are it's caused by you adding javascript on top, in the header. Try adding stuff at the end, just before the closing body tag, and see if it changes anything...

Comment: see here: https://jsfiddle.net/dqm8e473/ - so apparently your issue is only an issue in your specific environment, thus would be hard to fix here... so try to follow my advice and move js code to the end of your page...

Comment: What you mean by _the page flashes_?